# Tensorflow's inverse transformation to squeeze

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to use `tf.image.crop_and_resize` on an image that is a 3-D tensor with shape `[image_height, image_width, depth]`, yet `tf.image.crop_and_resize` expects a 4-D tensor with shape `[batch, image_height, image_width, depth]`.

How can I temporarily "un-squeeze" to insert a batch dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.expand_dims` to make a `3-D` image to a `4-D` shape of `batch size` 1.

```
tf.image.crop_and_resize(tf.expand_dims(image, 0), ...)
```